# Eclipse "Не видит" Theme.AppCompat.Light

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

Здравствуйте. Вчера столкнулся с проблемой в res/values/styles.xml; Код вот такой:

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

</style>
```

7-я строка,Ошибка на ней:

```
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
```

Я так понял "XX" на 5-й строке порядковый номер API

Помогите пожалуйста. Где может лежать Theme.AppCompat.Light?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Проверьте, подключена ли у Вас библиотека  `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'`. А вообще лучше использовать для разработки под Android - [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html), т.к. - [Support Ended for Eclipse Android Developer Tools](http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2016/11/support-ended-for-eclipse-android.html)

Comment: AppCompat это внешняя библиотека, чтобы она где то лежала, ее нужно сперва подключить в проект